# Dependency Injection not working When Interface is given as parameter

Tags: java, spring

This is my Controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(MyTest test){
        test.draw();
        return "homePage";
    }
}
```

on passing MyTest(Interface) as parameter to home method ,Spring does not inject its implementation class, instead throws an exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/spring-mvc-demo] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface com.managers.MyTest] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.managers.MyTest.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But on passing directly the implementation class i.e MyTestImpl it works fine .

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(MyTestImpl test){
        test.draw();
        return "homePage";
    }
```

Can you please tell the reason of Exception here in case of Interface.
Below is MyTest implementation class

```
@Component
public class MyTestImpl implements MyTest{

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("inside test");

    }
}
```

Spring.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers,com.ManagerImpl" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Use @Autowired with interface name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i'd like to point out that you are mixing different terminlogies.

Autowiring is as previously stated is a core concept of spring. As previously stated, [@Autowire](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) should be done on **setters** for non config beans*, here is the relevant phrase :

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method **or config method** as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

Secondly, here you are trying to inject a bean (@Component) into a MVC Controller and more specifically an interface of thus bean.

If you look closely at the documentation ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments)), you can see that Spring supports various parameters and will try as best as it can to pass them to your controller method.

The problem here is that Spring has no way of knowing what to pass to your method.
When the controller is called, spring will see that this parameter falls into the last category, ie `Any other argument` :

***If a method argument is not matched to any of the above, by default it is resolved as an @RequestParam if it is a simple type, as determined by [BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#isSimpleProperty-java.lang.Class-), or as an @ModelAttribute otherwise.***

Thus spring will consider this as a @ModelAttribute, but it cannot know how to map it as an interface cannot be instantiated, hence your error.

Now depending on your problem, either you :

Autowire your bean or interface as a member of your @Controller, ex :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{

    //might need @Qualifier if more than one implementation
    @Autowire
    private MyTest test; 

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        test.draw();
        return "homePage";
    }
}
```

or pass your ***implementation*** to your method controller.

> *Although i haven't found anything clear in the spring documentation that states what clearly is a config method, i'm pretty sure that does not apply to @Controller methods.

Comment: bit in bold answers the question perfectly. To clarify though: when you do `MyTestImpl`, that bean ISN'T being autowired in here.  Spring MVC is just creating a new instance of it, because it thinks you're using that thing as a Model.

Comment: I got the point, But still this "Secondly, here you are trying to inject a bean (@Component) into a MVC Controller and more specifically an interface of thus bean" point is not clear, sorry If i am being silly, Controllers are also bean so Dependecy injection should work here as with other Beans

Comment: If I add this method to my Cotroller It works perfectly fine.                                              @Autowired
 private void draw(MyTest test){
  test.draw();
 }

Comment: @xylo injecting into a method is supposed to be done only in config methods. This is not how a spring controller is supposed to be used. You should use Autowired on a field member or its setter.

Comment: @xylo edited in accordance to be more relevant about the config bean part.

Comment: @LaurentB thank you for your time and help,now it all have started make sense now. Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing is completely wrong.  Here is a working code,

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{
  private final MyTest test;

   @Autowired
   public HomeController(MyTest test) {
      this.test = test;
   }

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String home(){
      test.draw();
      return "homePage";
   }
}
```

Arguments to the methods anntotated with `@RequestMapping` should/will come in the form Pathvariable or RequestParams or just HttpServletRequest object itself. That is not how you autowire the instances.

***Dependency Injection works on Constructor, Field and Interface level. Not at a method parameter level***. Hope its clear.

Comment: yes this works fine. But I was just playing around.I wanted to know the reason why my code does not work. :)

Comment: Yes but according to Spring Docs You can also apply the @Autowired annotation to methods with arbitrary names and/or multiple arguments,and Autowiring any method works very well

Comment: can you give me the link where it says so.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation

Comment: This is not the DI issue but serialization issue. (I guess question is missleading). what OP is trying to do is correct except that (s)he needs to specify how to serialize the interface. In the interface the annotation "@JsonDeserialize(as=MyTestImpl .class)" should be added

Comment: @xylo As you can see in the documentation. It is either Field injection or constructor injection which is used. You cannot ask spring to inject to some random method.

Comment: @MichaelGantman of course it is a DI issue. If you look at the question. OP is not posting anything as body it is a simple get request. As you can see from the first comment OP has confirmed the same. What you are saying makes sense when you are sending a body which you want to serialize it to specific type

Comment: @pvpkiranI see what you are saying. Not sure who is right. Anyway, I tried to undo my down-voting, but it doesn't let me. will try later

Comment: @MichaelGantman what you are saying is a perfectly valid point. It applies when you are send a request body which you want to serialize to different types. I am only saying it doesn't apply here. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for late response,Thank you for your quick response @pvpkiran ,sorry stackoverflow is not allowing me to accept multiple answers

Answer (score 0):

Is your componentscan value covers the package where interface resides. Use @Autowired annotation for injection.

Comment: adding @Autowired on the method does not work either, It throws the same Exception

Comment: Have you keep the interface in the package com.ManagerImpl. One more thing package should in lower case

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct, except you need to tell Spring how to de-serialize your interface (i.e. which concrete class implementation is expected. If you use JSON serialization (usual Spring default) in your MyTest implementation add the following annotation

```
    @JsonDeserialize(as=MyTestImpl.class)
    public interface MyTest  {
    ...
```

Also assuming that you are using Post method change your Controller to:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public String home(MyTest test){
        test.draw();
        return "homePage";
    }
```

("produces" param may of course be text/html or whatever you return)